# how to find the fewest and most occur numbers in a shorting array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Can you please help me out with this code, it finds the most occur value but I couldn't figure it out how can I find the fewest.

```
      int arr[] = new int[] { 2, 3, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 2, 18 };
      System.out.println("Most Occurs : " + findElementThatOccursMostly(arr));
      System.out.println("Fewest Occurs : " + findElementThatOccursMin(arr));
     // a shorting array that finds the most occurs value which is 4 
     // but can't find the fewest occur number which is 18(only once)
     }

    int findElementThatOccursMostly(int arr[]) {
    int tempOccurrences = 0;
    int tempElement = 0;
    int mostOccurrences = 0;
    int mostElement = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (tempElement == arr[i]) {
            tempOccurrences++;
            if (tempOccurrences > mostOccurrences) {
                mostOccurrences = tempOccurrences;
                mostElement = tempElement;
            }
        } else {
            tempOccurrences = 1;
            tempElement = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return mostElement;
}
```

Comment: loop arr.length not array.length

Comment: where is the `findElementThatOccursMin` method ?

Comment: I've tried with the same code above and changed the greater symbol to smaller symbol. the code is same. I've played on it but didn't work. and I wanted to add it but StackOverflow gave an error to want me to add more comments, but if it's necessary I can add it too.

Comment: I am not sure to understand the goal of your methods. Do you want to find the most/less frequent number or the number with the most/less long series ? Actually, you do the second one.

Comment: In other words, I have to find the values that the numbers which mostly used on the array and less. For example in the array above 4 is the most used number (7 times) and 18 is the fewest(1 time). That code above is finding the most occur number but can't find the less :(

Comment: that is because for highest occurrence your logic is count the highest number, but the logic would not be the same for lowest since you are not going to count the highest so by flipping the sign it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

i can't find anyway to solve your problem with the code above so, here is my idea with another way to do both of them:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(2, 3, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 2, 18);
    System.out.println(mostCommon(list));
    System.out.println(lessCommon(list));
}

public static <T> T mostCommon(List<T> list) {
    Map<T, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (T t : list) {
        Integer val = map.get(t);
        map.put(t, val == null ? 1 : val + 1);
    }

    Map.Entry<T, Integer> max = null;

    for (Map.Entry<T, Integer> e : map.entrySet()) {
        if (max == null || e.getValue() > max.getValue())
            max = e;
    }

    return max.getKey();
}

public static <T> T lessCommon(List<T> list) {
    Map<T, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (T t : list) {
        Integer val = map.get(t);
        map.put(t, val == null ? 1 : val + 1);
    }

    Map.Entry<T, Integer> max = null;

    for (Map.Entry<T, Integer> e : map.entrySet()) {
        if (max == null || e.getValue() < max.getValue())
            max = e;
    }

    return max.getKey();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the elements and then go through it. So [1,4,2,6,4] -> [1,2,4,4,6]. If you see 1 then you see 2, you set minCounter to 1, then from 2 you see 4, minCounter is still 1. 4 to 4 , that's 2 occurrences so you dont update. At the end you return the position. Obviously you can manipulate this for find max occurrence .

Answer (score 1):

Your actual methods don't make you want to do.

You want to find the most/less frequent number whereas you find the number with the most/less long series.

Actually, it is just coincidence that `4` is returned as the most frequent number.
`4` appears 7 times but the longer series of it is `4`.

Change the input array by adding any number 5 times in a single series and you would see that it will be now returned as the most frequent value by your method even if globally this number appears less that `4`.

For example this :

```
int arr[] = new int[] { 2, 3, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 2, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18 };
```

should show the problem.

To solve your requirement, introduce a map to store the frequency of each number and then use this map to retrieve the number with the most and the less frequent.
Note that to find the value associated to the max and the min key value, you can take advantage of Java 8 that provides the `Stream.min()`/`Stream.max()` functions which you can pass to `Entry.comparingByValue()` as `Comparator` argument.

Here is a full code :

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Optional;

public class FindMinAndMaxFrequency {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      int arr[] = new int[] { 2, 3, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 2, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18 };

      Map<Integer, Integer> frequenciesByNumber = computeFrequency(arr);
      System.out.println("Most Occurs : " + findElementThatOccursMostly(frequenciesByNumber));
      System.out.println("Fewest Occurs : " + findElementThatOccursMin(frequenciesByNumber));
    }

    private static Map<Integer, Integer> computeFrequency(int[] array) {
      Map<Integer, Integer> frequencesByValue = new HashMap<>();
      for (int i : array) {
        int actualFrequency = frequencesByValue.computeIfAbsent(i, key -> 0);
        frequencesByValue.put(i, ++actualFrequency);
      }
      return frequencesByValue;
    }

    static int findElementThatOccursMostly(Map<Integer, Integer> frequenciesByNumber) {    
      Optional<Entry<Integer, Integer>> max = frequenciesByNumber.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .max(Entry.comparingByValue());
      return max.get().getKey();
    }

    static int findElementThatOccursMin(Map<Integer, Integer> frequenciesByNumber) {    
      Optional<Entry<Integer, Integer>> max = frequenciesByNumber.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .min(Entry.comparingByValue());
      return max.get().getKey();
    }    
}
```

**Output**

> Most Occurs : 4
>
> Fewest Occurs : 3

Answer (score 1):

Here's the most ridiculous stream-based way I could find that doesn't include custom reducers or collectors ;)

```
    Map<Integer, Integer> counts = Arrays.stream(arr).sorted().boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity()))
            .entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue().size()));
    System.out.println(counts.entrySet().stream().min(Comparator.comparing(java.util.Map.Entry::getValue)));
    System.out.println(counts.entrySet().stream().max(Comparator.comparing(java.util.Map.Entry::getValue)));
```

Not sure I'd use that in production ;)

Answer (score 0):

So i worked a couple of hours on your question and finally made from scratch the following code:

```
int findElementThatOccursMin(int[] array) {
    bubbleSort(array);
    int counter = 1; //counts the occurences

    int min_occ=100; //minimum occurences
    /*here put a starting value that is high relatively to the times a 
    number is in the matrix*/

    int num=array[0]; //the number that we want
    //start with 0 index in case the array has 1 element
    for (int i = 0; i <= array.length - 1; i++) {
        if (i == array.length - 1) { //avoid out of bounds exc
            if (array[i]!=array[i-1]) {
                num=array[i]; //in case it is one in last position
                min_occ=1;
            }
            else { //in case it is multiple times in last positions of array
                if (counter < min_occ) {
                min_occ=counter;
                num = array[i];
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        if (array[i] == array[i + 1]) {
            counter++;
        }
        else {
            if (counter < min_occ) {
                min_occ=counter;
                num = array[i];
            }
            counter=1;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Amount of min : "+min_occ+" times");
    //helped me see how many times the element was in the array
    return num;
}
```

I wrote this code based on logic and obviously as you can see i use bubble sort to sort the elements and "stick" them in neighbouring cells. This isn't the right way to write code but i did it to answer your question with a code that functions.

Here's the bubbleSort if you need it:

```
static void bubbleSort(int[] arr) {
    int n = arr.length;
    int temp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < (n - i); j++) {
            if (arr[j - 1] > arr[j]) {
                //swap elements  
                temp = arr[j - 1];
                arr[j - 1] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PS. I 'm not sure if the code works 100%. I tested many times with many combinations and it worked fine. If a mistake is found i'd be happy to hear!